# Не запускаетя программа на Python в Visual Studio. Что делать?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio

Когда я пытаюсь запустить программу

```
print('Hello World!')
```

В терминале появляется вот это:

```
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = '%VPROJECT%\..\sdktools\python\2.5'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'C:\Users\mk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\python.exe'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Users\\mk\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310-32\\python.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = '%VPROJECT%\\..\\sdktools\\python\\2.5'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '%VPROJECT%\\..\\sdktools\\python\\2.5'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\Users\\mk\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310-32\\python.exe'
  sys.prefix = '%VPROJECT%\\..\\sdktools\\python\\2.5'
  sys.exec_prefix = '%VPROJECT%\\..\\sdktools\\python\\2.5'
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\mk\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310-32\\python310.zip',
    '%VPROJECT%\\..\\sdktools\\python\\2.5\\DLLs',
    '%VPROJECT%\\..\\sdktools\\python\\2.5\\lib',
    'C:\\Users\\mk\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310-32',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x000019a8 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
```

Что делать?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Длинный путь -> разобраться с версиями python (у вас их минимум две), навести порядок в PATH. Короткий путь -> удалить все версии python, которые есть, затем установить по новой, не забывая указать `Add ... to PATH` при установке. Правильный путь -> использовать виртуальные пространства для каждой версии python и для каждого проекта

Comment: Dmitry, что такое виртуальные пространства? И уже пробовал переустановить Python, и нажимал при этом Add to PATH. Это бесполезно.

Comment: Обратите внимание, что у вас в логи лезут совершенно две разные версии Python 2 и 3. Они не имеют обратной совместимости. Первое, исправьте вопрос, чтобы ошибка была текстом (как работать с картинкой?). Второе, вы переустанавливаете одну из версий python, а что в это время делает другая? Виртуальные пространства это специальное решения для использования различных версий Python и различных версий модулей и пакетов

Comment: Dmitry, Я переустанавливал все версии Python. Вопрос я изменил.

Comment: удалите вторую версию и большене устанавливайте

Comment: Эникейщик, у меня не установлена вторая версия Python (если вы про Python 2).

Comment: В логах указаны две системные переменные `PYTHONHOME` и `PYTHONPATH`. Первая ведет к `sdktools` второй версии python. Даже если python2 не установлен переменная среды не корректная. Вторая переменная вообще пустая. Измените `PYTHONHOME`, чтобы путь указывал на нужную версию

Comment: Dmitry, как это исправить?

Comment: будет время напишу ответ сегодня, если никто не ответит. Если понимаете англ то вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38132755/10562663) можете найти ответ

Comment: Dmitry, https://stackoverflow.com/q/38132755/10562663 - там написано, что нужно удалить файлы виртуальной среды и сбросить "его". Как это сделать? А ещё там какой-то Ubuntu. Что это такое?

Comment: Смотрите ниже там решения для винды есть, [пошаговое](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45667503/10562663)